# I cant boot from my flash and use ubuntu live

Tags: usb, bios, flash, ubuntu-18.04

I created my flash bootable and want to use ubuntu live but my computer didn't recognize my flash I changed the first boot to all usb models I saw there.
what can I do to fix it?
I use windows

Comment: What OS does your computer currently use?

Comment: windows @Phoenix

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** 
 **NOTE**: This applies to all methods listed here. Make sure you plug in the USB before these steps and your USB port is not **faulty**.
And remember to enter the BIOS and turn **off** 'Secure Boot'.
**Windows 8/8.1**

1. Swipe to open the charms bar and select Settings.
2. Select power button and hold the `Shift` button before you select 'Restart'
3. You should boot into a blue screen with four selections.
4. Select Use a device.
5. Your USB should be listed in there.
6. Select it.
7. You should be in your desired OS.

**Windows 10**

1. Press/click the Windows button in the left bottom corner.
2. Select power button and hold the `Shift` button before you select 'Restart'
3. You should boot into a blue screen with four selections.
4. Select Use a device.
5. Your USB should be listed in there.
6. Select it.
7. You should be in your desired OS.

**Method 2**
Again, plug it in before these steps.

1. Boot into BIOS.
2. Enter 'Boot Device priority'.
3. There should be at least 2 boot options listed.
4. Change the order so that the USB goes first before Windows Boot manager (Or however Windows is listed).
5. Don't forget the 'Secure boot'! It must be off!
6. Save configuration and reset (reboot).
7. You should be in your desired OS.